# SignalR connection closed but still works after angularjs scope destroy

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have a SignalR hub proxy in angularjs factory like this.

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.factory("signalRHubProxy", ['$rootScope', "$timeout", function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    function signalRHubProxyFactory(serverUrl, hubName) {
        var connection = $.hubConnection(serverUrl);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

        connection.disconnected(function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                connection.start();
            }, 5000)
        });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });

                connection.start();
            },
            stop: function () {
                connection.stop();
            },
            connection: connection
        };
    }

    return signalRHubProxyFactory;
}]);
```

I used connection timeout because sometimes server does not listen, so I can retry.
I am using this factory in my controller:

```
app.controller("directiveController", function($scope, signalRHubProxy){

     var signalRProxy = signalRHubProxy(
             "url",
             "hubname");

    signalRHubProxy.on("datapush", function(data){

    });

        $scope.$destroy(function(){
        signalRHubProxy.stop();
        ??? how to kill signalr hub 
        })
})
```

But when I remove my directive, signalR still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you call `stop()`, it calls `disconnected` event, which will just start the connection again. You might need to check if the disconnection was intentional (with a simple boolean variable), then just avoid restarting the connection:

```
app.factory("signalRHubProxy", ['$rootScope', "$timeout", function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    function signalRHubProxyFactory(serverUrl, hubName) {
        var connection = $.hubConnection(serverUrl);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

        var manualStop = false;

        connection.connected(function () {
            manualStop  = false; // reset variable if connected
        });

        connection.disconnected(function () {
            if (manualStop)
                return;
            $timeout(function () {
                connection.start();
            }, 5000)
        });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });

                connection.start();
            },
            stop: function () {
                manualStop = true;
                connection.stop();
            },
            connection: connection
        };
    }

    return signalRHubProxyFactory;
}]);
```

Also, make sure `$scope.$destroy` is being called.

---

Some people recommend calling `$.connection.hub.stop();` instead of `connection.stop();`, although I don't really know whether it has some significant difference.